# dialog layout changing on 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-layout

i was trying to create custom dialog for my app and i was expecting it to be similar in older API's too. Here's what i've got on Jelly Bean(API 17):

[image: http://s3.postimg.org/xthkyt1jn/image.png]

looks awesome :) exactly how i want)

But then i test it on GingerBread (API 10) and here comes this

[image: http://s23.postimg.org/w2fc4fccb/oldshit.png]

Please help me. I dont know why my buttons shrinked.

Here's base layout for my dialog

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title_template"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:minHeight="64dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dip">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="8dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                android:src="@null" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/alert_image_content_description"/>
            <com.android.internal.widget.DialogTitle 
                android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                style="@style/QustomDialogTitleForOlderPlatfoms"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/customPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

then in java code i call addView() for the FrameLayout and add View inflated with this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            style="@style/EditTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your product title" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/product_amount"
                    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Enter your product amount" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/measures_spinner"
                    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel_product_creation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_new_product_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="Add"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code for the Dialog

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog{

/** The custom_body layout */
private View mDialogView;

/** optional dialog title layout */
private TextView mTitle;
/** optional alert dialog image */
private ImageView mIcon;
/** The colored holo divider. You can set its color with the setDividerColor method */
private View mDivider;

private View customView;


public CustomDialog(Context context) {

    super(context);

    mDialogView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.qustom_dialog_layout, null);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(mDialogView);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));      
    mTitle = (TextView) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
    mIcon = (ImageView) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    mDivider = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.titleDivider);
}

/** 
 * Use this method to color the divider between the title and content.
 * Will not display if no title is set.
 * 
 * @param colorString for passing "#ffffff"
 */
public CustomDialog setDividerColor(String colorString) {
    mDivider.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorString));
    return this;
}

public void setTitle(CharSequence text) {
    mTitle.setText(text);
}

public void setTitleColor(String colorString) {
    mTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colorString));
}


public void setIcon(int drawableResId) {
    mIcon.setImageResource(drawableResId);
}

public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
    mIcon.setImageDrawable(icon);
}

/**
 * This allows you to specify a custom layout for the area below the title divider bar
 * in the dialog. As an example you can look at example_ip_address_layout.xml and how
 * I added it in TestDialogActivity.java
 * 
 * @param resId  of the layout you would like to add
 * @param context
 */
public CustomDialog setCustomView(int resId, Context context) {
    customView = View.inflate(context, resId, null);
    ((FrameLayout)mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.customPanel)).addView(customView);
    return this;
}

public View getCustomView()
{
    return customView;
}

@Override
public void show() {
    if (mTitle.getText().equals("")) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.topPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    super.show();
}
```

}

this is how i use it

```
dialog = new CustomDialog(getActivity());
     dialog.setCustomView(R.layout.add_new_item, getActivity());
     dialog.setTitle("Add New Product");
     dialog.setTitleColor("#FFFFFF");
     dialog.setDividerColor("#FFFFFF");
     dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_new);
```

**UPD1///**
I figured out that the problem is that `FrameLayout` (`@id/customPanel`) provides insufficient space for `layout_height = "wrap_content"` to actually wrap it's content. If i set it's layout height in dp's - everything's all right, but it leaves lots of free space beneath on bigger screens. So how should i force this FrameLayout to show all of it's content?

Comment: Please post the code you are using to inflate and addView

Comment: Damian Walczak - it's CustomDialog.setCustomView(int resId, Context context) method

Comment: I was asking about methods from the AndroidSDK - did you use LayoutInflater.inflate at some point with root parameter set to null?

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
public CustomDialog setCustomView(int resId, Context context) {
    customView = View.inflate(context, resId, null);
    ((FrameLayout)mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.customPanel)).addView(customView);
    return this;
}
```

To:

```
public CustomDialog setCustomView(int resId, Context context) {
    FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout)mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.customPanel));
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    customView = inflater.inflate(resId, root, false);
    root.addView(customView);
    return this;
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

//EDIT:

Also, have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View) - maybe that's something better than your current implementation of CustomDialog.

Comment: not working :( 
I'm not interested in AlertDialog as base class. I've used it before and it was impossible to get custom dialog background with round corners with it. There was white space in corners, so i extended Dialog and it works.

Comment: have a look at this http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/ I believe it's something with inflating your views - check the line mDialogView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.qustom_dialog_layout, null); as well.